# javascript reload object

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object tag which loads a flash into the page. And if I click a button, this flash will append to a display popup box.

```
//first load
<object data="url.swf"></object>
//after alick will be appended to a div popup box
<div><object data="url.swf"></object></div>
```

In chrome and Firefox, the object will be reload after I append it into the popup box, and I need this reload action to show some information.

```
//after load
alert('have loaded')
```

However, In IE, there isn't any reload action, the information will not show. How I can reload the object manually

Comment: How to you append it to the div?

Comment: @Bergi I use jquery to do this. $('object').appendTo('div');